# Python Winreg - WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, registry, winreg

So I'm getting the error named in the title. Excuse me if I'm being naive but I'm a native OSX user and don't often write for Windows. In the code below I have granted `winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS` whilst opening the key within the conditional statement.

See the code below. Please give me advice also if you believe the code could be more concise. The code simply determines which subkey has a specific entry/value and then writes an entry/value to that subkey.

```
import _winreg as winreg
import socket

with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces') as key:
    keys = [winreg.EnumKey(key, i) for i in range(winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0])]
    for subkey in keys:
        with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces\\{0}'.format(subkey)) as finalkey:
            values = [winreg.EnumValue(finalkey, i) for i in range(winreg.QueryInfoKey(finalkey)[1])]
            for value in values:
                if value[0] == "DhcpIPAddress" and value[1] == socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()):
                    with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces\\{0}'.format(subkey), 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as writetokey:
                        winreg.SetValueEx(writetokey, 'TcpAckFrequency', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 1)
```

Comment: Run as administrator(And some values can't be change, on use, another user, read only, registered accesible application, so many, try device class for this).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not quite worked. My windows install is on a VM within OSX. For some reason, running cmd as an admin leads to the command line not being able to find the file; the exact same command running as a normal user executes the file, leading to the access denied error.

Comment: You go on wrong way ! Because need block/change on `OSX` your ethernet class are a `symbolic link` not a hardware. Maybe you acces this registry but my opinion do nothing/no change anything !